# azure datastore access issue

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I am new to azure.

I have created a azure datastore using the azure blob storage. I have 12000+ image files.

I want to use azure ml studio notebooks to perform some image processing on these images.

However, I don't know how to access these files using the azure ml studio notebooks. I am looking to read this files as an when I need in a way that one would mount a google drive into the google colab.

Can anyone guide me or point me towards a proper learning resource?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce same in my environment and create a mount path with ML studio.

```
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset, Datastore
subscription_id = 'Your_subscription_id'
resource_group = 'Your_ resource_group_name'
workspace_name = 'Your_workspace_name'
  
workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)
  
datastore = Datastore.get(workspace, "workspaceblobstore")
dataset = Dataset.File.from_files(path=(datastore, 'Relative_path'))

mounted_path = "/tmp/test"

mount_cont = dataset.mount(mounted_path)

mount_cont.start()
```

[image]

using below code you can check the dataset

```
import  os
print(os.listdir(mounted_path))
```

[image]

For information **refer** this [MS_Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-train-with-datasets?view=azureml-api-1#mount-vs-download).